# Cloning Object in Typescript, migration from Flow

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, functional-programming, flowtype

Essentially, I need a function that clones (i.e. deepcopies) objects that share some common properties. The "common property" is essentially just a tag called `op` for operation. So previously I have some code typed using Flow:

```
export function cloneExpr<E: Expr>(exp: E): E {
    if (exp.op === POINT) {
        return ((expr.makePoint(exp.p, exp.x, exp.y):any):E);
    } ... etc
}
```

where `Expr` is a union of a bunch of things like `Point`, `Line`, etc, all of which has this `op` field. The hard-casting somewhat ugly, but at least it works; i.e. if I `cloneExpr` a object typed `Point`, the return object is typed `Point` without me having to provide more typing info.

Now I'd like to migrate to Typescript, but I am having a lot of trouble. The hard-casting `return ((exp as any) as Point)` works in a vacuum, but my type guard keeps losing information so for instance I can't actually get the field `x` from the Point `exp` without failing the typing check. To get the typeguard to work, I've tried many variations in the function types, such as:

`function cloneExpr<T extends Expr>(exp: T): T`

where `Expr` is just something like `Point | Line`.

`function cloneExpr<T extends IsExpr>(exp: T): T`

where `IsExpr` is an interface I defined with just an `op` field in it.

`function cloneExpr(exp: Expr): Expr`

which I tried, but clearly I'll never get the proper input type back out.

So either I don't get the typeguard, or the return type is not the specific type that I inputted. I've also tried re-defining the objects using Interfaces and then providing a user-defined typeguard and what nots but to no avail.

What's the proper way to do this in Typescript? Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The failure to narrow `exp` from `E` to `Point` (or something like that) when you test `exp.op === POINT` would be addressed by [this suggestion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24085).  In the meantime, you can achieve the same level of type safety you had with Flow by copying the argument to a local variable of type `Expr`:

```
export function cloneExpr<E extends Expr>(exp: E): E {
    const exp1: Expr = exp;
    if (exp1.op === POINT) {
        return expr.makePoint(exp1.p, exp1.x, exp1.y) as any as E;
    }
    // ...
}
```